# XMLin not parsing XML properly

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I have an XML as follows in `$response_xml`

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;wholeSaleApi&gt;&lt;credentials&gt;&lt;referenceNumber&gt;&lt;/referenceNumber&gt;&lt;/credentials&gt;&lt;wholeSaleOrderResponse&gt;&lt;statusCode&gt;666&lt;/statusCode&gt;&lt;description&gt;Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&lt;/description&gt;&lt;/wholeSaleOrderResponse&gt;&lt;/wholeSaleApi&gt;</string>
```

When I parse it using

```
my $xs = XML::Simple->new();
my $xmlDS = eval{ $xs->XMLin($response_xml) };
```

I get the following data structure

```
$xmlDS =  {
          'xmlns' => 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/',
          'content' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><wholeSaleApi><credentials><referenceNumber></referenceNumber></credentials><wholeSaleOrderResponse><statusCode>666</statusCode><description>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</description></wholeSaleOrderResponse></wholeSaleApi>'
        };
```

How do I get the `content` portion from this?

Comment: The subject of your question says that `XML::Simple` doesn't parse XML properly, but the body of your question just asks how to access an element from the hash you get back. Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

What you get is a hash reference. You can use the follwoing syntax to get to the particular key:

```
my $content = $xmlDS->{content};
```

Comment: one more way to access content : my $content = ${$xmlDS}{content};